# Is "latte" a countable noun?

Tags: grammatical-number, nouns, meaning-in-context, uncountable-nouns

[image: screenshot]

I have learned that liquids are uncountable, except for measurements such as "three cups of water."

So, does "three lattes" in this context refer to three cups of latte?

Comment: Thanks for editing Alenanno.A question, why using refer instead of refers ? Does it means "Three lattes" is phural ?

Comment: When you ask a question with the form "Does [subject] [verb] [additional info]?" the verb goes to the infinite form, because "DOES" is already playing that role... :)

Comment: So "Does" is the real subject of the verb "refer", Thank you :D

Comment: I want to know why this is voted-down so i can improve the quality of question later.

Comment: No, it's not the subject... For example "Does the Earth rotate?": "_the Earth_" is the subject, "_rotate_" is the verb, and "_does_" is needed to form the question, I don't remember its role name at the moment

Comment: So i just need to remember that when using "Does [subject] [verb] [additional info]?" just use the verb without "s".

Comment: Yeah. That's the main rule, I'd say...

Comment: @Alenanno - I think you meant "[infinitive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/infinitive)" form, not "[infinite](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/infinite)"...

Comment: @MT_Head yeah lol xD

Comment: I just thought about something this morning.
Does the following structure is the correct way to explain why we don't have to put "s" in "rotate"

The Earth rotates. --> The Earth does rotate. --> Does The Earth rotate ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a specific usage that concerns items on a menu. It is perfectly acceptable to say "three lattes" or "one water" because you are referring to a specific item like a bottle, rather than a substance.

Comment: So in this case we can say "two waters" or "three waters" as well ?

Comment: Yes. It is understood that "waters" means "bottles of water."

Comment: Or glasses of water; basically "servings of water".

Comment: The prescriptivist in me would like to argue for "3 cafes latte," but I'm laughing too hard.

Comment: @The Raven: the Italian in me would argue the same...

Answer (score 3):

In Australia, a few years ago, Kylie Minogue (aka 'The Singing Budgie') featured in a TV commercial for Coca Cola.

In the commercial, she ordered **Two Coke**, and this caused some public debate.

The answer came from the Coca Cola company itself, which I can summarise by saying *Coke is a trademark and correct usage of the mark requires it to be both singular and plural* — Owners of such valuable marks take these things *very* seriously.

**But** I'm not aware that anyone considers the word *latte* a trademark, so it should be safe to treat it as countable as jackgill described.

Comment: Even with *Coke*, the Cola-Cola company doesn't get to decide what happens to the word in the English language.  They have every right to try, but what happens happens.  People ask for "cokes" all day long in every English speaking restaurant that serves the product.

Comment: Which is probably why there was a public outcry: firstly because Kylie was heard to say something *ungrammatical* and secondly because the Coca Cola company took it so seriously. But, then, she *was* using the word in a trademark context -- namely, advertising.

Answer (score 2):

As a native American English speaker, I find "Three lattes for takeout. Is that all?" to be entirely grammatical and natural. Saying that all liquids are uncountable is an oversimplification of the actual rules for determining countability.

Comment: That's because you're using *lattes* as short form of *cups of latte*. Liquids are still uncountable (they have no proper shape by definition!), you're counting the containers and/or the servings.

Answer (score 2):

As a longtime restaurant worker I consider myself an expert on beverages. Coffee is brewed in quantity. We make a pot of coffee and then pour it out into cups to serve it, so the coffee is uncountable and the cups are countable. Three coffees is short for three cups of coffee, as others have noted. 
Latte, on the other hand, is not brewed in quantity, but individually. Each one is a separate product and can be counted. The same goes for cappuccino, espresso and their variants.
You can ask for more coffee, but you ask for another latte.